# obtener un valor de un array dentro de otro(mas complejo)

Tags: php

Tengo un *array* que contiene otro *array* como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito obtener el valor de `[extra]`, pero el array puede tener más de un `[#]` necesito también diferenciarlos, tengo unos rompiendome la cabeza y no logra dar con una opción viable.

En mi código tengo un `foreach` que contiene los valores del array completo y destino sus opciones a `$c[id], $c[cantidad], $c[base], $c[ingredientes], $c[salsa], $c[extra], $c[opciones]` pero tengo un `for` que obtiene los datos pero no funciona:

```
$ing = explode(",", $ingredientes);
//$ong = explode(",", $extras);
$cont=0;                     
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ing); $i++) {
    if ($ing[$i] != "") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM c_ingredientes WHERE id = " . $ing[$i];
        try {
            $resp = $conn->obtDatos($query);
            if ($conn->filasConsultadas > 0) {
                foreach ($resp as $dts) {
                    $ingrediente = $dts['ingrediente'];
                    //$precio = $dts['precio'] * preg_split('/,/',$canti)[$i]; 
                    $precio = $dts['precio'] * $extras[$i];  
                    //$precio = $dts['precio'] * $canti2[$i];                                      
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }
        //$temp = preg_split('/,/',$canti)[$i];
        //$temp = $ong[$i];
        echo "<h6>($extras[i]) $ingrediente</h6>";
        $ext.= " " . preg_split('/,/',$canti)[$i] . " " . $ingrediente . "<br>";

        $importe += $precio;
    }
}
```

El resultado del código anterior es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vendrán más valores que entrarán al *array* principal y tendré que tomar sus respectivos extras, ¿cómo hago que funcione?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Benvenido a StackOverflow en español. Por favor, no publiques imágenes con código, publica el código directamente en tu pregunta.

Comment: @jachguate no son imagenes de codigo, son fotos de resultados, el codigo php esta respectivamente en el bloque de codigo, las fotos son peramente salidas que me da el codigo al imprimirlo

Comment: Correcto, son datos de texto en formato `json`, y una tabla, pero para los efectos de mi comentario, diría que vale para lo mismo. Creo que es preferible también que datos como esos se incluyan como texto.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ong = explode(",", $extras);
```

descomentando lo de arriba y editando lo siguiente logre que funcionara, dentro del for edite lo siguiente:

```
$precio = $dts['precio'] * $ong[$i];
```

y mas abajo edite y descomente esto:

```
$temp = $ong[$i];
echo "<h6>($temp$ingrediente</h6>";
```